# Invoke AWS Lambda function from AWS java SDK

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8AXN.png) Is it possible to invoke aws lambda function from the aws publish subscribe sample java code? Can we invoke lambda function from our java code? if yes then how?

Comment: Try first and if some challenge, then mention that specifically

Comment: I don't know from where to start my lambda is ready and the pub/sub sample code from aws java is ready I don't know how m I supposed to trigger my lambda function from my code.

Answer (score 2):

**Invoking an AWS Lambda Function from Java**

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeResult;
// ...
// (1) Define the AWS Region in which the function is to be invoked
Regions region = Regions.fromName("us-east-1");
// (2) Instantiate AWSLambdaClientBuilder to build the Lambda client
AWSLambdaClientBuilder builder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                                    .withRegion(region);
// (3) Build the client, which will ultimately invoke the function
AWSLambda client = builder.build();
// (4) Create an InvokeRequest with required parameters
InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
                           .withFunctionName("myFunctionName")
                           .withPayload("{ ... }"); // optional
// (5) Invoke the function and capture response
InvokeResult result = client.invoke(req);
// (6) Handle result
...
```

The above will invoke Lambda synchronously; however, you can also invoke asynchronously using Java Futures or callbacks.

**Invocation with Access Key and Secret Key**
The above sample will utilize the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain to utilize environment variables, EC2 Instance Profile, etc. when invoking the function. While this is often best practice, there are also scenarios when you may need to provide access and secret keys. To do so, we only need to make a small change to the code above:

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
// (1a) Instantiate credentials
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new 
  BasicAWSCredentials("myAccessKey", "mySecretKey");
// (2) Modify to leverage credentials
AWSLambdaClientBuilder builder = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials));                                     
  .withRegion(region);
```

Comment: Thank you so much so this will invokelambda from my code itself I am sending a screenshot of my code actually I am new to this and it will be of great help if I can solve this thank you

Comment: yes hope so and can you please guide where o I add this in my code it is a normal pub/sub aws sdk java sample code.

Comment: It is just how you handle the outcome from InvokeResult result = client.invoke(req);

Comment: Region, AWSLambda and all these are classes that we need to define right because I am not able to import it

Comment: i have added a screenshot of my code please see to it and see if the code canbe applied

Comment: Give credit when credit is due: https://medium.com/@joshua.a.kahn/invoking-an-aws-lambda-function-from-java-29efe3a03fe8